# How do I create a professional quality desktop icon?

Tags: icon, text

I would like to create a professional quality icon.  Currently, I have created an icon with IcoFX.  The icon looks great -- when it is scaled at the right size.  When it gets scaled to the wrong size, the text in the icon becomes fuzzy.  Is there anything that I can do about this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use software to create an *.ico file with different frames -- one for each resolution. I can recommend [Gif Movie Gear](http://www.gamani.com/), although it isn't free.

With a multi-resolution *.ico, the icon wiil display the frame that is called for instead of scaling the available frame. This way, you control the icon's appearance at all display sizes.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the information that I needed to know exactly.  I did not realize that an *.ico file could contain all the sizes (16*16 to 256*256).  I had been saving all of the different sizes in an *.icl file, assuming that it would scale from within the icon library.  

* I have been able to correctly create my icon from the information you have given me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you have to make each size of icon more or less from scratch as oppose to simple down sample.

Try the [Icon handbook](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/) by John Hicks.  It's good primer in making professional looking icons.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I will definitely take a look at that handbook.